# Is it possible to run Windows VM from bootable SSD?

Tags: windows, external-disk, virtualization

I have made a bootable Windows 10 SSD, which I use to boot into Windows on my iMac. This works fine, Windows runs natively and SSD over USB 3 if fast.

But now, I want to have my cake and eat it to - I would like to be able to boot into OS X (Sierra) and start a Windows VM which would boot from the same SSD instead of virtual hard disk. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on the internets:

[Adding a raw disk to a VirtualBox machine on OSX](https://elliottucker.net/adding-a-raw-disk-to-a-virtualbox-machine-on-osx.html)